# AttributeError: 'FFmpegPCMAudio' object has no attribute '_process

Tags: python

how I can fix this error?

code:

```
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
    global is_playing
    if not ctx.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel.")
        return

    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

    if not voice_channel:
        await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel.")
        return

    voice_client = nextcord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if not voice_client:
        voice_client = await voice_channel.connect()

    if is_playing:
        await ctx.send("The bot is already playing audio.")
        return

    url_youtube = url

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'extractaudio': True,
        'audioformat': 'mp3',
        'outtmpl': 'C:\\Users\\alshh\\Videos\\%(title)s.%(ext)s',
        'yes-playlist': True,
        'playlist-random': True,
        'embed-thumbnail': True,
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info_dict = ydl.extract_info(url_youtube, download=True)
        if 'entries' in info_dict:
            for entry in info_dict['entries']:
                print(f"Downloaded: {entry['title']}.{entry['ext']}")
        else:
            print(f"Downloaded: {info_dict['title']}.{info_dict['ext']}")

    is_playing = True
    player = nextcord.FFmpegPCMAudio(f"C:\\Users\\alshh\\Videos\\{info_dict['title']}.{info_dict['ext']}")
    voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: play_next(ctx) if e else None)
```

error :

```
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alshh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 143, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/alshh/.vscode/discord/Recording/1.py", line 63, in play
    player = nextcord.FFmpegPCMAudio(f"C:\\Users\\alshh\\Videos\\{info_dict['title']}.{info_dict['ext']}")
  File "C:\Users\alshh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nextcord\player.py", line 281, in __init__
    super().__init__(source, executable=executable, args=args, **subprocess_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alshh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nextcord\player.py", line 144, in __init__
    self._process: subprocess.Popen = self._spawn_process(args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alshh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nextcord\player.py", line 163, in _spawn_process
    raise ClientException(executable + " was not found.") from None
nextcord.errors.ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alshh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1355, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\alshh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1003, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alshh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 152, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.
Exception ignored in: <function AudioSource.__del__ at 0x000002881ADFF0D0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alshh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nextcord\player.py", line 95, in __del__
    self.cleanup()
  File "C:\Users\alshh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nextcord\player.py", line 214, in cleanup
    self._kill_process()
  File "C:\Users\alshh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nextcord\player.py", line 170, in _kill_process
    proc = self._process
AttributeError: 'FFmpegPCMAudio' object has no attribute '_process'
```

[image]